# what is meaning of oracle database query: primary key references t_name(col_name)?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

```
create table books
( 
    bid   number(5)  primary key,
    name  varchar2(30)
);

create table members
( 
    mid    number(5)  primary key,
    name   varchar2(30)
);

create table issues
( 
    bid    number(5)  primary key
           references books(bid),
    mid    number(5)
           references members (mid)
);
```

I have 3 tables first two tables are simple but what is the meaning of third table as I know foreign key references `t_name(col_name);` but what is meaning of primary key references t_name(col_name) and col_name references t_name(col_name); ?

Comment: What does this have to do with PL/SQL or mysql?

Comment: view this  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: @GoodBadandUgly: the MySQL manual won't really help for an Oracle question (and besides MySQL would _ignore_ the above foreign key constraints)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name before the question was edited,it was tagged with mysql also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is no special case. Here the primary key `bid` of table `issues` is referencing to the column `bid` of table `books`. This simply means that `bid` of `issues` will have only those values which are present in `bid` of `books`. It will act as the primary key of table `issues` so it will have unique value and it's values will be limited to those contained in `books` table.

So it simply means it is primary key value with it's values in table `books`.

Comment: i understand first one and in second without primary key referencing mid of table members means it is not necessary to have unique values and values can be duplicate from members table in issues table .is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

It is the same as any other `references` statement.  This is saying that the primary key also references `Books(bid)`.

I can think of two reasons why this type of construct would be used.  First, the "issues" entity could be a subset of the "book" entity.  This would allow additional issues-specific columns to be stored in `issues`, without cluttering up `books`.  It also allows foreign keys to either `issues` or `books`.

The second reason is that this is one way of implementing vertical partitioning.  This occurs when a table has a lots of columns.  For performance reasons, you want to separate them into different storage areas.  This is sort of similar to what columnar databases do, but it has the overhead of the additional primary key.